# React-native android images flashing on load

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-image

I am having trouble on Android where the images are flashing only on Android and I cannot seem to find a solution.

I have attached a video below to show the problem

Here is my Flatlist

```
  <FlatList
   ListEmptyComponent={_listEmptyComponent}
   initialNumToRender={2}
   keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
   renderItem={renderItem}
   data={walletData}
   contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start', paddingBottom: 80, marginTop: 20 }}
   style={{ padding: 5, marginTop: 40, backgroundColor: '#ffff' }} />
```

Here is my renderItem Function:

```
     const renderItem = ({ item }: any) => { return (
            <View style={{marginTop: 20}}>
            <Card title={item.category} logo={item.logoImage} name={item.name} address={item.shortAddress} background={item.backgroundImage} Key={item.chainId} Stamps={item.schemes} Vouchers={item.vouchers} />
            </View>
          )
   }
```

Here is the Card Image part:

```
  <View style={styles.top}>

          {/* Background image */}
          {loading &&
            <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', width: '100%' }}>
              <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="black" />
            </View>
          }
          {

            <FastImage
              style={{
                height: Dimensions.get('window').height / 4.5,
                width: '100%',
                borderRadius: 12
              }}
              onLoadStart={() => onLoading(true)}
              onLoadEnd={() => onLoading(false)}
              source={{
                uri: background,
                priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
              }}
              resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}>

          {/* Logo image */}

              <View style={styles.test} >
                <Image
                  style={styles.imageTop2}
                  source={{ uri: logo }}
                  onLoadStart={() => onLoading(true)}
                  onLoadEnd={() => onLoading(false)}
                />

              </View>
            </FastImage>

          }

        </View>
```

Video Link: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/_v758YEg9iY

Comment: your youtube video is no longer available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some logic cause screen to rerender 2 times. iOS caches pre-loaded images and use cached images for the next rerender without refetch them.

Android doesn't cache t images and fetches them again for the next rerender which takes some milliseconds to be ready and results in flickering.

The solution is to avoid a second rerender or wait until all data fetching finishes before app render a FlatList.

Try to remove this state change.

```js
...
onLoadStart={() => onLoading(true)}
onLoadEnd={() => onLoading(false)
...
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer! Would you have an examples of code waiting until data is fetched before rendering a flatlist?

Comment: Can you check the answer update

Comment: You genius! thank you very much!!! Such a simple fix but works very well!